# What is wrong in the below codes which describes circles and lines in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have drawn two lines. But , when I try to draw a circle on it, it doesn't work.

```
a(1:400,1:400,1:3)=255;
a(200,1:400)=0;
a(1:400,200)=0;
imshow(a);
```

It works perfectly. But while I execute the below codes to draw a circle, the above lines vanish from the figure.

```
centrepoint=[a(200),a(200)];
viscircles(centrepoint,198);
```

What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: You should probably post this on http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. When executing your code I get:
[image]

When executing:

```
figure(1);
a(1:400,1:400,1:3)=255;
a(200,1:400)=0;
a(1:400,200)=0;
imshow(a);
centrepoint=[200,200];
viscircles(centrepoint,198);
```

I get:[image]